# Synchronize 2 databases installed locally with Xampp

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization, navicat

I've 2 computers connected to Internet. Each one has Xampp installed, with a local mysql database.

Is it possible to sychronize these 2 dbs ?

I use Navicat. The sync works well with a local database to a server database, using tunneling. But what about the sync between 2 PCs dbs ?

Thank you very much for your help,

Cheers,
François

Comment: I don't know much about Navicat, but if you can use it to sync a local machine to a server, can't you use it to sync the two PCs?

Comment: it is probably overkill for your purposes, but if you use innoDB engine for your tables you can do replication using transactions

Comment: close, belongs on serverfault.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [SymmetricDS](http://symmetricds.org).  SymmetricDS is web-enabled, database independent, data synchronization/replication software. It uses web and database technologies to replicate tables between relational databases in near real time. The software was designed to scale for a large number of databases, work across low-bandwidth connections, and withstand periods of network outage.