# Linking 2 DBs from 2 different servers

Tags: mysql

I have production DB(mysql) in server1, i want to transfer records from prod DB to another DB residing in server2.

How to link bother server's DB?

i.e.i want to transfer 60 days of data from 'table1 of DB of server1' to 'table1 of DB of server2'

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an answer here:
[Synchronize 2 databases installed locally with Xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111319/synchronize-2-databases-installed-locally-with-xampp)

Recommended solution was to use [SymmetricDS](http://symmetricds.codehaus.org/).