# Update automatically a database table with the information of a table of another database on the same server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I already asked the question, and tried the solutions which was given to me here in stackoverflow, but it was not was i was searching: [Select columns across different databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674115/select-columns-across-different-databases)

So i repost my question:
i managed to install xampp with wordpress on localhost. In a subfolder of wordpress i installed a php program. Everything works well, but i have a problem, i want my wordpress members to be able to login and use my php program (a web app). The problem is that's i'm just started to learn php a few weeks ago, so i can't really do it, i don't have money to spend on a developer, so this site is my only help.

I found an easier way for me to do essentially the same, but i have some problems implementing it: i want to link bitnami_wordpress.wp_user (first table with wordpress user information) with cm2.cm_user (php app table with user information). Essentially i want to update the table ucm_user informations based on information on wp_user automatically, without me intervening in phpmysql, i.e. if someone update his password on wordpress for example i want his password also to be updated on database2, if i delete or add an user on wordpress i want them also to be deleted or added on database2 from my web app. All this automatically without me intervening.

The informations on the two database are:

```
bitnami_wordpress.wp_user: user_id email password
```

and

```
cm.cm_user: ID email password name last name
```

The sql query did not do what i wanted: Add, Update or Delete AUTOMATICALLY a user in `cm.cm_user` when i add, update or delete a user on wordpress.

Should i use triggers? If yes, how?

So can anyone help me please?

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: You mind supplying this query that `"did not do what i wanted"`?

Comment: "All this automatically without me intervening." So you believe in magic then? At some point in time, you need to intervene and do programming to make this work.

Comment: If you do not know much PHP wouldn't it be easier to replicate the mysql information? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111319/synchronize-2-databases-installed-locally-with-xampp or you can manually do replication with this tutorial http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-howto.html

Comment: I'm sorry if i was not clear, essentially i want the database part to be automatic. Let's say a user on wordpress updates his data, the data at this moment would be updated only on the first database's table not the second. What i want is essentially when the user or i update a data on wordpress (manually of course), the data should be updated automatically on db1 table1 and db2 table2 (only this part automatically without me intervening)

Comment: how do you automatically add a user when name and last_name are unknown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a [`TRIGGER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html) on `bitnami_wordpress.wp_user` for `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`. The catch is that you [cannot make a cross database update from within a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421699/cross-database-trigger-in-mysql), but you can call a [`STORED PROCEDURE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-routines.html) from a `TRIGGER` that does update a table in a different database.

Comment: Thank you doublesharp, that's what i was searching!